# Работа с пулом потоков

Tags: c#

Есть метод, который выполняет определенные задачи, если таковые есть. Вопрос относительно данного метода *"QueueUserWorkItem(otvet)"*, если количество уже созданных потоков данным методом в пуле будет уже максимально (в данном случае 10) и они ещё не завершены, то каков будет результат если будет вызван этот метод в 11-й раз? Будет создана некая очередь, до момента завершения предыдущих потоков? Если да, то какой размер данной очереди?

```
public void pool_potok()
{     
     count_thread = 10;    
     count_thread2 = 10;      
     ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(count_thread, count_thread1);
     ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(0, 0);
     while (work)
     {
         ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(otvet); 
         Thread.Sleep(500);
     }
}
```

В свою очередь метод pool_potok() вызывается таким образом по нажатию на кнопку

```
     work = true;
     Thread work_tread = new Thread(pool_potok);
     work_tread.IsBackground = true;
     work_tread.Start();
```

P.S. Прошу прощения, если не корректно описываю вопрос.

Comment: `Будет создана некая очередь, до момента завершения предыдущих потоков?` хотя бы одного из них

Comment: `Если да, то какой размер данной очереди` Какая разница? Скорее всего она бех ограничений, но скидывать миллиард задач в пул я бы не стал.

Comment: @tym32167 Мне интересен данный вопрос. Да, размер очереди может не столь важен, а вот создание такой очереди все же произойдет. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, очередь будет, об этом говорит и название метода, и его документация `Queues a method for execution. The method executes when a thread pool thread becomes available.`

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо.